# Stopping all threads working on queue with a Keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have the following code:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

num_worker_threads = 10

# some items to work on
def source():
    return xrange(400)

# the actual work to be done
def do_work(smth):
    # some really heavy task here
    print("{}\r".format(smth))

# worker that retrieves data from queue and executes work
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)  #use args to pass args
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

# queues items to work on
for item in source():
    q.put(item)

# blocks until work is finished
q.join()
```

How do I stop all threads when I press Ctrl+C? When I do it, the program execution continues.

I've seen similar questions on StackOverflow, but they don't use `join()`.

I am confused on what exactly I should wrap with `try..except` here and how should I stop the threads?

Answer (score 1):

By calling `q.join()`, you are just waiting for the threads to end. You need to be able to tell a thread (from the main thread) to stop its execution.

A good way to do this is to change the implementation of your worker. Instead of being a function, it should be a class that inherits from threading.Thread.

You can give the `Worker` an attribute that can be changed from the main thread that tells it to stop doing work.

```
import threading
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.keep_doing_work = True
        self.q = queue
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while self.keep_doing_work is True:
            item = self.q.get()
            self.do_work(item)
            q.task_done()

    def do_work(smth):
        print("{}\r".format(smth))

num_worker_threads = 10

my_threads = []

try:
    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = Worker()
        my_threads.append(t)
        t.start()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for t in my_threads:
        t.keep_doing_work = False
```